# rspec valid? invalid method for nil class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, bdd

This makes no sense:

```
describe SessionsController do
  context "We should login to the system and create a session" do
    it "should create a session" do
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, :user_name => 'Sample-User', :password => '12345678910')
      post :create, :user => {:user_name => 'Sample-User', :password => '12345678910'}
      assigns(:user).valid?.should == true
    end
end
```

when run I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: assigns(:user).valid?.should == true
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `valid?' for nil:NilClass
```

I do this type of check in other tests with no issue, I have `require 'spec_helper'` at the top of the file.

how is this not a valid method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked Michael Hartl's tutorial ? see [Sign-in Tests](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-signin_tests)